# Mongodb will not start

Tags: mongodb

It has been a while since I have used Mongodb and I am running into a problem.  I have an EC2 instance that had Mongodb running on it, but I had turned off the instance for a few months.  After turning the instance back on, Mongodb will not start correctly.  No log file is being created so I do not know what is causing the problem.

When I type:

```
sudo service mongodb start
```

I get the message:

```
mongodb start/running, process 2432
```

but mongo is not actually running and a mongod.lock file is being created.

If I type:

```
mongod
```

by itself, Mongodb will actually start and be usable.  But, I must leave the terminal window up and not cancel out of the command to keep it running.  I have to open up a second terminal window to access my databases.  I guess my main question is how I get the mongod service to stay running itself without having to leave a terminal window open with the command running.

Sorry if my explanation doesn't make sense.  Hopefully you get what I mean.  Anyone have any idea what I am missing?  I had this problem before months ago and was able to solve it.  Sadly, I didn't write down the missing ingredient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, run command using [Nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup)

```
nohup mongod &
```

Then you can terminate you terminal.

Comment: That seems to work.  Thank you vanda.  I haven't used that command before though, so there must be another way to do it as well.

Comment: @DanielLeach Yeah there's a lof of way to do so, but if you ask me, use `sudo service mongodb start` and check the log file to find out why mongodb can't start.